# How to Write hyperlinks using spreadsheet gem in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

The [spreadsheet gem](http://rubyforge.org/projects/spreadsheet/) isnt documented properly, so I cant understand how can I write hyperlinks using spreadsheet gem. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This script will create a spreadsheet with a link in the first cell

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spreadsheet'

book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
sheet1[0,0] = Spreadsheet::Link.new 'www.google.com', 'link text'
book.write '/tmp/spreadsheet_with_link.xls'
```

Comment: but when I try to write again into same file, previously written data is not there.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Guide you have to write to a new file name: https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md